# How to randomly split images from a folder in to two folders for k-fold cros validation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, split

I have a datafile whit images and txt files in other folders and I want to split the images randomly in to two folders for K-fold cross validation. I want to do this so that I have a set of images that I can use to validate the models generated whit the K-fold cross validation.
For this split I want to take randomly 16 images .png out of this folder and put that into an other folder for later use and put the remaining images in a folder to be used for the K-fold cross validation. My question is how do i make this split into random folders.
I tried

```py
tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory,  labels='inferred', label_mode='int', class_names=None, color_mode='rgb', batch_size=32, image_size=(256, 256), shuffle=True,seed=None, validation_split=None, subset=None, interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False, crop_to_aspect_ratio=False, **kwargs)
```

But that did not work (or I did it wrong).

So how do I split images that are in different folders into two folders that can be named differently and have a specific amount of images in them?

Answer (score 0):

this is what eventually worked.

```
directories = os.listdir(ALL_FILES)
    validation = random.sample(directories, 16)
    K-fold = [dir for dir in directories if dir not in validation]

    for f in validation:
        print(f)
        source_dir = os.path.join(ALL_FILES, f)
        print(source_dir)
        destination_dir = os.path.join(name for folder seld to, f)
        print(destination_dir)
        shutil.copytree(source_dir, destination_dir)

    kf = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True)  
    folds = kf.split(K-fold)
```